# Reset User data loaded by auth component

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have auth component working greatly till I implemented a page for the user to change the user's info. I experienced some unknown results till I found out that after user's info being changed by that action, the user data loaded by auth component in session still remains the same. I wanted to know if there is any way to force auth component reload the user data from database again?
I considered re-logging in the user but it makes the logs complicated and places some bad traces in program. is there any more beautiful way to do so?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$this->Session->write('Auth', $this->User->read(null, $user_id));

you got to update it, cake does not do everything for you ;)

Comment: I came to this before but the problem is that if I later change the way Auth component acts then it won't store the User data under 'Auth.User' key but some other keys, then I have to change every where such thing is happened. I thought there may be a way to automate reloading the user's data from Auth component itself.

Comment: dude, i just pasted the code that formats it exactly the way auth does, just try it.

Comment: mohamnag I too needed this functionality. What I did was paste @dogmatic69 's awesome snippet inside an if statement that lives in my AppController's beforeFilter. The if statement just check if the user is logged in, if they are, dogmatic's snippet updates the data in the $this->Auth->user()